# Edited program showing result for an earlier program

Tags: java, netbeans-7

I ran a simple Calculator program with functions such as addition and multiplication and the program gave the required results. But after discussion on here, I tried to edit my code but after running the project its still giving me errors for my earlier program. All the commented code is from my earlier program.

Please find both my program below and kindly tell me what I am doing wrong. After  changing the values the program still gives the same result.

```
public class Calculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 6;
        int b = 5;
        // int c;
        // c = addition(a,b); //calling method and passing values for a and b
        System.out.println(addition(a, b));
    }

    public static int addition(int a, int b) {
        // int c;
        // c= a+b;
        return a + b;
    }
} // gives result of 11
```

Comment: Have you done a "clean and build"?

Comment: Yeah, your code runs fine.

Comment: You should be a lot more specific on what those errors are. I don't see anything wrong at a first glance...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I have not done a clean and build. How does that help?

Comment: @user3580294 the problem is if i change the values of a and b to 10 and 200 respectively it still gives me the same error

Comment: It will delete all the previous built content and re-compile your source files from scratch...

Comment: @user3769423 *What* error? Be more specific. We can't read your mind

Comment: @MadProgrammerthe clean and build has worked. THank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine, you probably didn't compile the program before running it.
If you are using eclipse enable automatic build in eclipse menu: Project -> Build Automatically
Or compile it in command line:

`javac Calculator.java

java Calculator`